# Help with 'hello world' jquery-ui modal-form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to display a modal form using jquery ui. I've adapted an example but I cannot get the dialog to launch. I'm sure it's very simple but can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

The page displays initially but when I click on 'Create New User' nothing happens.

The code is below - also (easier to read) at http://pastie.org/1000263 .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
   $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
     'Create an account': function() {
      var bValid = true;
      allFields.removeClass('ui-state-error');

      if (bValid) {
       alert(name.val());
       $(this).dialog('close');
      }
     },
     Cancel: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
     }
    },
    close: function() {
     allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
    }
   });

   $('#create-user')
    .button()
    .click(function() {
     $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
    });


  });
  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
   /*demo page css*/
   body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
   .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
   #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
   #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
   ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
   ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
   ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
  </style> 
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Welcome to jQuery UI!</h1>

 <p style="font-weight: bold; margin: 2em 0 1em; font-size: 1.3em;">YOUR COMPONENTS:</p>
   <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

    <form>
    <fieldset>
     <label for="name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
     <label for="email">Email</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
     <label for="password">Password</label>
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
   </div>  
   <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the files you're linking to are included correctly?  Also if you're just starting out, might as well use the latest versions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code worked fine when I removed .button()

```
   $('#create-user')
    .click(function() {
     $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
    });
```

I'm not really sure what .button() does anyways. I'm not sure I've seen it before.

The javascript console in chrome said:
"Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'button'"

The javascript console will be very useful for "why things don't work".

Comment: In ie, you can press F12 for javascript/css debugging, and firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) is great for firefox.

Comment: +1 - good point, `.button()` is jQuery UI 1.8+, he's using UI 1.7.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was trying to integrate with some existing code that already uses jq 1.3.2 (which jqui 1.8 doesn't support) however now you guys have pointed out the problem with .button() I'll have to take a different approach. Thanks again.