# jQueryUI dialog (modal form) demo code not working

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm extremely new to jQuery, although not new to javascript in general. I'm trying to use the UI dialog widget. I've downloaded a .min.js file containing the dialog widget and a few others, and already have the core .min.js.

I copied the demo code directly from the [UI doc for modal form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) and pasted it into a plain html file. Clicking the button does not work; nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me if there's something else I need to do to use the demo code? And how do I go about debugging this jQuery stuff in Chrome? (I do have FireBug Lite installed; just haven't quite figured out how to use it for jquery.)

I can post pieces of code if anyone can tell me something specific to look for, but the entire html file, simple as it is, is over 100 lines. Here's a [link to my sample](http://www.esthermstrom.com/test/dialog.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$( "#create-user" ).button is not a function

it is supposed to be

```
$( "#create-user" ).click(function(){.....
```

Comment: Actually button is apparently a function in the newest version of jquery, which I just found out (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019486/help-with-hello-world-jquery-ui-modal-form).

Comment: yeah but since 1.8 and you're using 1.7.3

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. Unfortunately, jqueryui claims that v1.8 is for jquery1.3.2+. We're on 1.3.2, so I guess I can just use a link instead of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the `.button()` call, you forgot to include a reference to jQuery UI.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can see from the src that I'm loading jquery-ui-1.7.3.dialog.min.js, which is a custom download from jqueryui.

Comment: @EmmyS, my mistake. I think the problem is with your custom download then, your `.button()` isn't working because you don't have the correct dependency. Try removing the js files and replacing them with this http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js and this https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: @EmmyS Also, your link to the JQuery UI is for 1.7, and, according to the question you linked to below, .button() is only available in Jquery 1.8 +.  Although then you will have to grab a newer version of JQuery as well, as you are linking to 1.3 and the 1.8 UI code is not compatible with that version

Comment: I don't think jQuery 1.3 supports 1.8 UI anyway. Just use the latest versions @EmmyS :P

Comment: I can't "just use the latest versions". I'm in a corporate environment where we are specifically limited to certain versions, and right now that version is 1.3.2. No big deal - I wasn't aware that button() wouldn't work. I can just change it to a link instead.

Comment: @EmmyS, I don't know what is contained in your custom download, but if you can't upgrade to the latest versions, then just ensure that you have all the dependencies required by modal. You can post the source here if you want and we can take a look. Although chances are the .button() call was just breaking your method chaining. If you get rid of it, it might work.

Comment: @Brandon - that's what I did - got rid of the button call, and made the trigger a link instead. Works fine now.